# noUiSlider: If I have a slider with two handles, how can I tell which of the handles is being moved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

[noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) allows you to create range sliders with multiple draggable handles, as per the snippet below:

```js
var output = $('#output');

$('#range-slider').noUiSlider({
    start: [0, 100], 
    range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
    }
}).on('slide', function(evt) {
    // In this event handler, I want to see which of the two sliders is being moved
    // Is there a property of the 'evt' parameter which would tell me this?
    output.html($(this).val().join(' - '));
});
```

```css
body { padding: 30px 30px; }
#range-slider { width: 300px; } 
#output { margin-top: 30px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/c8a70344bebb0b69a09adf12a1e7cc08894f8c3b/distribute/jquery.nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/c8a70344bebb0b69a09adf12a1e7cc08894f8c3b/distribute/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="range-slider"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

In the event handler for the `slide` event (which is fired continuously as each slider handle is dragged), I want to know which of the handles is currently being moved. I can't see anything in the documentation about this, and inspecting the `evt` parameter of the event handler in a browser's dev tools reveals a mass of data, but none which I can see would identify the handle.

I could do something messy, like binding a `mousedown` event directly to the handle elements and setting the value of a higher-scoped variable which can be accessed from within the event handler to contain the last moved handle ID/class... but I don't really want to, especially if there's a cleaner way. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better handling of this was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/commit/1adfeeba224ad287bd39c25ddd3c8d13d9c2239f), so you now get the handle index as an event callback argument:

```
$('#range-slider').noUiSlider({
    start: [0, 100], 
    range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
    }
}).on('slide', function(values, handle, unencoded, tap, positions) {
    // 'handle' will either be 0 or 1 depending on which handle caused the event to fire
    var whichHandle = handle === 0 ? 'LEFT' : 'RIGHT';
    output.html(values.join(' - '));
});
```

There is more information about the other callback arguments in [the documentation](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/#section-binding).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kwj8opsq/1/

use evt.target and check for noUi-active class

```
if($(evt.target).find('.noUi-handle-lower').hasClass("noUi-active")) lowerHandle=true;
if($(evt.target).find('.noUi-handle-upper').hasClass("noUi-active")) upperHandle=true;
```